# Is there a good way to have granular control over error handling in `cats.effect.Resource`?

Tags: scala, error-handling, scala-cats, cats-effect

currently, in order to handle exceptions in different resources differently, I'm doing something akin to this:

```scala
def resource1: Resource[F, Service1[F]]
def resource2: Resource[F, Service2[F]]
def resource3: Resource[F, Service3[F]]
def runProgram(Service1[F], Service2[F], Service3[F]): F[ExitCode]

resource1.use(r1 =>
  resource2.use(r2 =>
    resource3.use(r3 =>
      runProgram(r1, r2, r3) //handles its own exceptions
    ).handleErrorWith(e => logger.error(e)("error during service 3 setup").as(ExitCode.Error))
  ).handleErrorWith(e => logger.error(e)("error during service 2 setup").as(ExitCode.Error))
).handleErrorWith(e => logger.error(e)("error during service 1 setup").as(ExitCode.Error))
```

This works fine, but it's not hard to see why it doesn't scale well. I've tried using `.attempt` directly on the `Resource` but it doesn't seem to catch anything. I can imagine figuring out a way to do it in a for comprehension if I use `allocate`, but I'd rather not If I don't need to. Anyone know a better way?

### Edit

So it turns out that the resources I was creating were starting up their own threadpool and doing a lot of impure async processing which caused unstable behavior. It seems that `attempt`, `onError`, `handleErrorWith`, and friends should work just fine for resources that are constructed well.

I am unsure why my nested code seemed to be able to get around the instability, while the other `MonadError` based solution didn't. Without sufficient evidence to the contrary I am forced to conclude that it must just be lucky timing.

Comment: So you want to log an error if the creation of `ServiceN` fails?

Answer (score 4):

`Resource[F, *]` is a `MonadError` just like the underlying `F`, so you can use all of the associated machinery to factor out the logging code and use convenient syntax:

```scala
def withErrorLogging[A](
  resource: Resource[F, A],
  name: String
): Resource[F, A] =
  resource.onError {
    case e => Resource.eval(logger.error(e)(s"error during $name setup"))
  }

(
  withErrorLogging(resource1, "service 1"),
  withErrorLogging(resource2, "service 2"),
  withErrorLogging(resource3, "service 3")
).mapN(runProgram).use(identity).handleError { _ =>
  ExitCode.Error
}
```

Comment: unfortunately this seems to have the same problem as `attempt`. In your code, if an exception is thrown when starting service 1, the only place it will show up is that final `handleError`

Comment: No, this does cause an error message to be logged when the initialization of the resource fails.
Besides, it's hard to give a good answer when you haven't explained at all what the problem is, except for your remark that “it doesn't scale”. I don't know what that is supposed to mean in this context.

Comment: I retract my statement. I was encountering some instability due to some impure code running on a different threadpool, so you're probably right about this